# Full the image in tableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am trying to develop an application that using tableView in Xcode using Swift programming. I have already done display the image in the tableView but the image not in full size. The image still not covered the area of the cell.

How to make the image full size?

I am using Xcode 6 and using Swift Programming.

Below is the example of the code.

```
class FoodListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var food:AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("food", ofType: "plist")
        let food2 = NSArray(contentsOfFile:path!)

        food = food2!   
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return food!.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellfood", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var imageName = UIImage(named: food![indexPath.row].objectForKey("gambar")! as! String)
        cell.imageView!.image = imageName

        return cell
    }
```

here is the screen shot what I got...

http://104.223.3.210/namia/hm/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-14%20at%202.02.47%20AM.png

Comment: Are you talking about the left hand side empty space?

Comment: @Amit89 yes..left hand side

Comment: That is default in current iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code may be helpful.

```
cell.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: can you tell me what kinda cell your making use over there ?

Answer (score 0):

In current version it is default value of 15 pixel.

For your query two work around can be

1. If you are using storyboard, go to storyboard -> select your view controller -> open "Attribute Inspector" on right -> select "Separator InSet" -> change it custom from default and give 0 instead of 15 in "Left" field.
2. If the above is not working, create a custom cell sub class of `UITableViewCell` and add a `UIImageView` inside it which will start from zero position of of the cell.

Note : If you are not using custom cell, remove the cell initialisation code and use this -         `let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"cellfood")`